# Generating multiple combinations of strings

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list of n letters as strings such as:

```
input: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

What I need to do is create all possible combinations of these letters with given length, for example if:

```
L = 2
output: ["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["A", "D"], ["B", "C"], ["B", "D"], ["C", "D"]

L = 3
output: ["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B", "D"], ["A", "C", "D"], ["B", "C", "D"]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? You've tagged [tag:itertools] and [tag:combinations], so did you look into either of those?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get permutations of a specified length.

```py
from itertools import permutations 

print(list(permutations(my_list, L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your standard combinations which is available in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools

characters = "ABCD"
print(list(itertools.combinations(characters, 2)))
print(list(itertools.combinations(characters, 3)))
```

You'll find other useful functions for iterating inside itertools such as permutations.

Comment: You don't capture every combination, for example where is B, A  in character length 2 or have I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use itertools and [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).  You pass it your list of characters and the length of the permutation.

```
import itertools

my_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
print(list(itertools.permutations(my_list, 2)))
# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')]
print(list(itertools.permutations(my_list, 3)))
#[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'D', 'B'), ('A', 'D', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'D', 'A'), ('B', 'D', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'D'), ('C', 'D', 'A'), ('C', 'D', 'B'), ('D', 'A', 'B'), ('D', 'A', 'C'), ('D', 'B', 'A'), ('D', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'C', 'A'), ('D', 'C', 'B')]
```